# How can I repeat through objects on click or swipe using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, dom

I have a list of object element like:

```
$scope.products = [
    {
        name: 'First News Heading',
        content: 'Lorem ipsum',
        cover: 'img/img1.jpg'
    },
    {
        name: 'Second News Heading',
        content: 'The veldt fox. Bright vixens jump; dozy fowl quack. Quick wafting zephyrs vex bold Jim.',
        cover: 'img/img2.jpg'
    },

];
```

And I want to display then like:

```
 <div class="thumbnail">
     <img ng-src="{{ product.cover }}">
      <p class="title">{{ product.name }}</p>
      <p class="content">{{ product.content }}</p>
 </div>
```

using ng-repeat displays all of them together. but I want to use a click or swipe up to display next-next element.

Comment: I think you are looking for carousel.https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/carousel

Comment: pls add your ng repeat template

Comment: thumbnail div is the ng-repeat template

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
 <div class="thumbnail">
    <img ng-src="{{product.cover}}">
    <p class="title">{{product.name}}</p>
    <p class="content">{{product.content}}</p>
 </div>
 <input type="button" ng-click="previous()" value="Previous" />
 <input type="button" ng-click="next()" value="Next" />
```

JS:

```
$scope.currentPosition=0;
$scope.product=$scope.products[0]; //initialize the product var with first element
$scope.next=function(){
    $scope.currentPosition++;
    if($scope.currentPosition <$scope.products.length)
        $scope.product=$scope.products[$scope.currentPosition];
    else
        $scope.curentPosition=$scope.products.length-1;
}
$scope.previous=function(){
    $scope.currentPosition--;
    if($scope.currentPosition >=0)
        $scope.product=$scope.products[$scope.currentPosition];
    else
        $scope.curentPosition=0;
}
```